# SQL beginner question

Tags: query

I have a table, shown below, with the following columns: ClientID, PoNumber, Consignment_Number,Status

As you can see, an individual client will have multiple PO numbers (purchase orders) and each PO will contain few deliveries.
I'm trying to pull list of PO numbers and all consignment numbers if there are any planned consignments on PO and at least one consignment has completed status

I would expect to see just green rows as final output,

Any help would be appreciated

[image]

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
WHERE poNumber IN (SELECT poNumber FROM tablename WHERE Status = 'Complete')
AND   poNumber IN (SELECT poNumber FROM tablename WHERE Status = 'Planned')
```

Another option, a bit more complicated to understand, and a bit more expensive (at least on the very small subset of data I tested it with):

```
SELECT * FROM @tablename
WHERE poNumber IN (SELECT poNumber FROM @tablename
                   GROUP BY ponumber HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(Status)) > 1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much - i have used option one as it was easier for me to understand.